# Apache Camel Set route Exception in Exchange Header

Tags: apache-camel

I am using the Camel sql component and want to use the onConsumeFailed  to update the record with exception stacktrace when the transaction fails.

Table Structure:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory
(
itemnbr integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('inventory_itemnbr_seq'::regclass),
location integer,
loctype character varying(2) ,
color character varying(5) ,
brand character varying(5),
soh double precision,
camel_is_read integer DEFAULT 0,
exception character varying(500) ,
CONSTRAINT inventory_pkey PRIMARY KEY (itemnbr)
)

In my camel route I am using the onConsumeFailed option as below

```
sql://<select statement>?dataSource=#dataSource&onConsumeFailed=update inventory set camel_is_read = 0, exception=:#exception where itemNbr= :#itemNbr
```

I have created onException on route as below and set the root cause  to header property "exception" as  .

```
     onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Throwable ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT,
                    Throwable.class);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("exception", ex.getCause());
        }
    });
```

When exception happens for a transaction, below error is thrown while updating the row

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeExchangeException:Cannot find key [exception] in message body or headers to use when setting named parameter in query
```

How can we access the header property from the route during route execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple expression language to get exception

exception=:#${exception}

https://camel.apache.org/components/next/languages/simple-language.html

Comment: Thanks!! It works partially. We can use :#${exception.message} to get the String message from exception object. Ex:  To update the error in table column  we can use   onConsumeFailed=update inventory set  exception=:#${exception.message} where itemNbr= :#itemNbr, for SQL component.